# What Runes do you carry for Junglers or off junglers?

Tags: league-of-legends

What runes does Lee sin or shyvana like champs use? What runes do odd junglers like jarvan and allister use?

Comment: Hi @Enix, your question was closed due to the fact that it is overly broad. Asking for rune setups for entire champion types (junglers and off-junglers) is not very constructive for our site. We focus on Q&A, one answer for one question, and this question would necessitate an answer that is too broad to be actually useful.

Answer (score 2):

Armor yellows are almost mandatory on junglers.

Reds are typically Armor Penetration, Attack Speed, or flat AD. Outside of that, blues and quints are usually up to personal preference. Common blues are flat AS, flat, and scaling MR. Quints tend to be movespeed, AS, ArPen, flat AD, or gold per ten. Just check out guides on, like, http://www.solomid.net to get a better idea of what's optimal on any given jungler.

Answer (score 1):

As a jungler, its important to **ALWAYS** run armor yellows, as it helps you to not take nearly as much damage as you would without them. for lee sin i run flat attack damage reds and quints, and magic resist per lvl blues, so you can survive ganking the AP/magic oriented champions. Shyvana is pretty much the same way, attack damage reds, armor yellows, and magic resistance blues, except i run movement speed quints on her as she needs as much movement speed as possible to make up for her weak ganks, and to help her counter jungle more effectively. But for most other odd jungles like you say, run the usual attack speed reds to clear faster, and the staple armor yellows with magic resist per lvl blues. for them though you can either pick the movement speed quints or more attack speed.

Answer (score 1):

Lee Sin and Shen both use energy and have a different jungle than champions that require mana.  For these junglers, attack speed reds, armor yellows, magic resist/lvl blues, and move speed quints are fairly common.

The additional attack speed increases damage dealt to minions, armor reduces damage received, magic resist is useful as the game progresses, and move speed lessens time in jungle and increases the chance of ganking (esp with red buff).

Attack speed is also useful since many junglers have abilities based on attacks, like Lee Sin's passive  or Shyvana's twin bite.

Comment: Shyvana does not use energy.

Comment: Not really different, it depends what your attitude on jungling is and where you will start.  If you want to gank early like level 2, then you generally start at red. There are some junglers that are a little more dependent on blue, but by no means need it especially with the new jungle giving mana and health back as you clear small camps.